# Error when creating an object with constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I ran into an error when using this code:

```
class Box {
public:
    Box (int);
};

Box::Box (int a) {
    //sample code   
}

int main() {
    class Anything {
        Box box (5); // error: expected identifier before numberic constant
                     // error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant
    };
}
```

The error appears on the five I filled in under class Anything.
The issue disappears if I just write.

```
Box box (5);
```

Without the Anything class around it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean to declare the class `Anything` inside `main()`?

Comment: @mchl12 you can "fix" your code by writing `Box box = 5`, but I can't say if it'll make sense in general.

Comment: The problem is for creating object box from class Box using a constructor. I want to fill in multiple arguments for the constructor at some point. For the sake of simplicity I used only one argument in the example. There is no problem if class Anything is removed.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you use? Some old versions don't implement the relevant C++11 features; you would need a workaround for them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside `Anything`,

```
Box box(5);
```

is not valid for declaring the member variable and initializing it.

You can use:

```
class Anything {
    Box box;
    public:
       Anything : box(5) {}
};
```

or

```
class Anything {
    Box box = Box(5);
};
```

or

```
class Anything {
    Box box{5};
};
```

Comment: You could do this but it is nonsense.  What is the point of the class?  In the first example you cannot even create an object because you have a private constructor.

Comment: `Box box{5};`  should also do the trick for the in-class member initializer.

Comment: The first example shouldn't compile. Did you want to write `Anything() : box(5) {}`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because `box` here:

```
 class Anything {
    Box box (5);
 };
```

Is not an object, it is a member of the class anything. You need to initialize it in the constructor ([see here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)). If you want to be able to create a `box` you would need to do something like this:

```
 class Anything {
        Box box;
    public:
        Anything() : box(5) {}
 };
```

Then you can create an anything object as such:

```
Anything anything;
```

And it will contain a `Box` object `box` initialized with 5.

*Of course all of this is pointless because you cant actually do anything with `Anything`. It has no other data members or functions ...*